# Error: Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, npm

I am working on a nodeJs project and using a npm package **mysql2** for mysql database.

My MySql Configuration:-

```
let mysql = MYSQL.createConnection({
  host: `${config.mysql.host}`,
  user: `${config.mysql.user}`,
  password: `${config.mysql.password}`,
  database: `${config.mysql.db}`,
});
```

When I am using a query

```
async function getUsers ({pageNumber}) { // suppose pageNumber = 1
  const [result] = await mysql.execute(
   `SELECT * FROM user LIMIT ?,20;`,
    [pageNumber]
  );
  return result;
}
```

The above code is working fine. But when i am trying to multiply any number with pageNumber,it throws error **Error: Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute**

Ex.

```
async function getUsers ({pageNumber}) { // suppose pageNumber = 1
  pageNumber = pageNumber * 20; // here we multiply 20 with pageNumber (20 is the row limit)
  const [result] = await mysql.execute(
   `SELECT * FROM user LIMIT ?,20;`,
    [pageNumber]
  );
  return result;
}
```

above code throws the error.

Note:- type of pageNumber is number not string.

Please help.

Comment: Are you share the first block of code works for you? because I'm trying to reproduce the issue but the first one generate an error for me.

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug introduced in MySQL version 8.0.22, I'm getting the same error after updating from 8.0.19. Not sure about the cause or a proper solution, in the interim I'm mapping the values to strings, as per https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/1239#issuecomment-718471799, which seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

is like a buggy, use interpolation like this(yes is a bad practice, but you can make a solution meanwhile) :

```
const [result] = await mysql.execute(
   `SELECT * 
    FROM user 
    LIMIT ${pageNumber},20;` 
  );
```

and, if the variable is a string, put '  ' around the interpolation

```
`SELECT * FROM user WHERE xname = '${x}'  ;`
```

Comment: This is terrible advice. Using interpolation completely removes the benefits of using `execute` over just `query`. Plus when using interpolation, it is very important that you are aware of the dangers of `SQL injection`. If you go this route you should be knowledgeable on ways to mitigate this risk.